# TDD & Git commit comments

Tags: git, tdd, commit

I'm using TDD in my project.
I write a test, watch it fail, write code to make it green and commit with Git.
I have read about commit first development, but I don't understand how to do it with this workflow.
If I'm testing a layer of the application (like Service or Repository), what kind of comment should I write in the commit, to look good to somebody else?
Should I write the name of the test?
How are you dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commits for TDD changes should be no different to any other changes. Therefore, you apply the same rules for the commit message.

Here's [an example from tpope](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html):

> `Capitalized, short (50 chars or less) summary`
>
> `More detailed explanatory text, if necessary.  Wrap it to about 72
>   characters or so.  In some contexts, the first line is treated as the
>   subject of an email and the rest of the text as the body.  The blank
>   line separating the summary from the body is critical (unless you omit
>   the body entirely); tools like rebase can get confused if you run the
>   two together.`
>
> `Write your commit message in the imperative: "Fix bug" and not "Fixed bug"
>   or "Fixes bug."  This convention matches up with commit messages generated
>   by commands like git merge and git revert.`
>
> `Further paragraphs come after blank lines.`
>
> `- Bullet points are okay, too`
>
> `- Typically a hyphen or asterisk is used for the bullet, preceded by a
>     single space, with blank lines in between, but conventions vary here`
>
> `- Use a hanging indent`